# Anchor Tag for sharing URL on Facebook, Twitter etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, anchor

I am trying to find a way (JQuery etc.) of auto updating the URL for sharing on Facebook, Twitter etc.

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http//xxxxxxxxx.co.uk/index.html/" class="button button--icon button--facebook"><img src="../img/facebook.png"></a>
```

Except I want to replace "http//xxxxxxxxx.co.uk" with something so that if the URL of that page were to change, it would grab that URL and insert it into the tag, without me having to update it manually?

Comment: Although it can be accomplished client-side, this kind of thing is should be done server-side if you ask me. I find it strange to deal client-side with something that will be the same for each and every client, and perfectly predictable (unless you have the same site sharing different domain names, but even in this case you probably have a "master" domain you communicate about)

Comment: So how would you accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: My first step would be to come to an agreement with the client over the price. Then do it. To be serious, I think you should read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question isn't actually in the appropriate format for SO. You basically should show your attempt(s) to solve the issue first, then come back here with a clear reproducible issue, if you happen to have one. Ideally, following my first comment, I would expect your first trial to be server side. In the end we're anyway talking about just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean that you want to dynamically build this `href` from the current page's URL?  Something like this?:

```
document.getElementById('yourAnchorElement').href =
    'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' +
    encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
```

It just gets the current URL, URL-encodes it to be used as a query string parameter, appends it to the known base URL, and sets it to the `href` of the element.

You don't *need* to use `document.getElementById()`, any method you use to identify the target element is fine.

Comment: This works fine for FB and Twitter but LinkedIn doesn't like it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` you can do something like this on `document.ready`:

Here is a jsFiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/41tabh5e/)

```
$(function () {

   var fbShare = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='
   // grab url of the page:
   var url = window.location;

    // loop through all elements with class 'button--facebook' and update href:
    $('.button--facebook').each(function () {
         $(this).attr('href', fbShare + url);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function to generate share buttons with jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="fb"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var fblink = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{link}}";

$(document).ready(function () {
    generateLink('fb','http://www.google.com');
    generateLink('fb','http://www.stackoverflow.com');
});

function generateLink(id,link) {
    $('#' + id).append('<a href="' + fblink.replace('{{link}}',link) + '">Share</a>');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/991ofmhL/)

I replaced you image with "Share" for completeness in JSFiddle without access to your image, but that can be replaced to suit your needs.